# Job Scheduling in Haskell

Tags: haskell, job-scheduling

What work has been done so far in Haskell to the effect of scheduling jobs for execution in a native way?  Here's an sketch of what I am thinking.

Say I have a function `work` I want executed at `Date`, presumably in the future (if not, we can just schedule it for immediate execution).  In this case, let's just pretend there's some kind of `Job` monad for this to occur in.

```
type JobId = ..
schedule :: Date -> Job () -> Job JobId
```

This is then passed into a (preferably persistent) scheduling mechanism that will execute the scheduled job at an appropriate time and also provide some kind of reference `JobId` so the job can be inspected or rescheduled.  I've used a couple different job scheduling libraries in Ruby, such as Delayed Job and Sidekiq.  Is there similar work in the Haskell community on the job scheduling problem?  Perhaps with Haskell the nature of the language gives rise to a pattern simple enough, given some primitive functions, a library isn't wholly necessary?

Comment: What capabilities are you looking for exactly?

Comment: You may want to look at this [library](https://github.com/tbk303/hcron). It seems to be offering some primitive scheduling operations.

Answer (score 6):

Why not `forkIO` and `threadDelay`?

Here's a sketch of what you can do:

```
type JobId = ThreadId
type Job = IO

schedule :: Date -> Job () -> Job JobId
schedule date job =
  forkIO $ do
    time <- getCurrentTime
    threadDelay (delay time)
    job
  where
    delay time = error "TODO: compute the delay from `time` and `date`"
```

Comment: He says he wants this to be persistent, which suggests hooking into some system-level scheduler to me.  Perhaps this is just me mis-interpreting the question.

Comment: Thomas is correct.  I'm hoping for some ability to recover from a crash or shutdown.  Persistence is necessary.

Comment: @thegravian Oh. It definitely complicates things. Since there's no way to serialize a function in Haskell, you'll have to create some "label" data structure, which will encompass all the possible jobs. Then you'll be able to use it with some persistence layer, be it some MySQL driver or something like Acid-State. I'm sure you'll get a more thorough answer soon.